# using view property animator to move items in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-animation

I'm learning animation in android.

I was trying to build a grid view and make the item switch position when user click every two of the items (like candy crush)

Here is the code that I'm using

```
    myGrid = (GridView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.my_grid);
    myGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    myGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 

            if(mVPosition == null){
                mVPosition = position;
            }
            else{
                   View item1View = v;
                   View item2View = myGrid.getChildAt(mVPosition);

                   int originalPos1[] = new int[2];
                   item1View.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos1 );

                   int originalPos2[] = new int[2];
                   item2View.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos2 );

                   swVId = mThumbIds[position];
                   mThumbIds[position] = mThumbIds[mVPosition];
                   mThumbIds[mVPosition] = swVId;   // Swap items' image
                    // mThumbIds is used as image source of myGrid define in adapter code

                  item1View.animate().x(originalPos1[0]).y(originalPos1[1]).setListener(new AnimatorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                                    }
                                    }); 

                item2View.animate().x(originalPos2[0]).y(originalPos2[1]).setListener(new AnimatorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                                    }
                                    }); 
     mVPosition = null;

                }
    });
```

The problem is the items move incorrectly in y direction. if I only let them move horizontally, two items will switch locations, but if I want them switch vertically, they all move down to some strange place on the grid

and also, the item that moved cannot be clicked again.

Is this problem have something to do with the using of "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" and the ViewPropertyAnimation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must first define gridview location by getLocationOnScreen method and subtract it from each item like the following code

```
int gridLoc[] = new int[2];
myGrid.getLocationOnScreen(gridLoc);
.
.
.
item1View.animate().x(originalPos1[0]-gridLoc[0]).y(originalPos1[1]-gridLoc[1])....
.
.
.
item2View.animate().x(originalPos2[0]-gridLoc[0]).y(originalPos2[1]-gridLoc[1])....
```